# Pernicious USB-stick stall problem. Reverting workaround fix?

Tags: linux, usb, proc, sysctl

There's an issue with Ubuntu that hasn't been fixed yet, where the PC freezes or gets really slow whenever it is copying to an USB stick (see [Why is my PC freezing while I'm copying a file to a pendrive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107703/56755), http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/ and https://askubuntu.com/q/508108/234374).

A workaround is to execute the following commands as root (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107722/56755) for an explanation) as root:

```
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

How do I revert these changes? When I restart my PC, will it get rolled back to default values?

Comment: You need to write an init file. I would rewrite you question to ask about persisting changes to `/proc`, and not mention usb-sticks in the title. But keep the detail as an appendix to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [sysctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) parameters. You can set them either by writing to `/proc/sys/CATEGORY/ENTRY` or by calling the [`sysctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) command with the argument `CATEGORY.ENTRY=VALUE`. These settings affect the running kernel, they are not persistent.

If you want to make these settings persistent, you need to set them at boot time. On Ubuntu, create a file in the directory `/etc/sysctl.d` called `becko-vm-dirty.conf` containing

```
# Shrink the disk buffers to a more reasonable size. See http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 16777216
vm.dirty_bytes = 50331648
```

To revert the changes, write the old value back. There is no “restore defaults” command.

Note that these parameters are a bit peculiar: there are also parameters called `vm.dirty_ratio` and `vm.dirty_background_ratio`, which control the same setting but express the size as a percentage of total memory instead of a number of bytes. For each of the two settings, whichever of `ratio` or `bytes` was set last takes precedence.

Comment: A thousand times thank you for revealing to me where this can be set at boot time. But this is quite "global", if you will - are there ways of being more specific (setting these variables at boot time for I/O directed towards removable media only, because I might be otherwise happy with the Linux kernel's I/O policy towards internal HDDs/SSDs)?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist AFAIK this setting is global because the kernel doesn't maintain separate totals for dirty buffers on different block devices, but I'm not an I/O tuning expert.

Answer (score 1):

There [is no way to reset these values to their default of 0](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues/267#issuecomment-574228289). As of kernel 4.4, doing so [fails with `EINVAL`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e260ad01f0aa9e96b5386d5cd7184afd949dc457).