# Unmounting external drive takes tremendously long

Tags: ubuntu, external-hdd, lubuntu, unmounting

This morning I copied around 200GB of data to a quite old USB2.0 1TB external drive. The copying took around 2 or 3 hours. Afterwards I unmounted & the unmounting is still going on (after more than 12 hours).

It should not be related to [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive/107722#107722) since I only have 4GB of RAM.
And I don't think it's related to the [The pernicious USB-stick stall problem](http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/)

I am afraid to interrupt the unmounting process & retry it. Is this a common problem? How should I proceed in order to not corrupt some of the data that I copied onto the external drive.
I am running lubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have a look at iotop, see whether there's still anything writing to the device ... did you spot anything untoward in dmesg?

Comment: in iotop there is no constant writing going on, just some smaller things that I can't clearly identify popping up every other second.

Comment: in dmesg there was nothing particularly untoward (as far as I can tell as layperson)

Comment: Did you run `sync`?

Comment: I did after you wrote it, thank you. But no apparent influence as far as I could see...

Comment: I'm having the same problem just now. Also no notable write activity in iotop. Weird.

Comment: I finally just unplugged the drive, and it apparently didn't cause a problem. Diffed the whole file, and it's ok. This is on Peppermint Linux 10.